How to handle Slack trigger_id expiration for opening modals after a delay?
I'm working on a Slack app that opens modals in response to user actions using the views.open API. According to the Slack documentation, the trigger_id used to open modals is valid for only a few seconds. However, in my use case, I need to open a modal after a short delay (possibly up to a minute).
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

I successfully trigger the modal immediately after a user interaction, and it works fine. But if there’s any delay in using the trigger_id, I get an error stating that the trigger_id has expired.
I've tried capturing and storing the trigger_id, but it becomes invalid after a few seconds.

This is the response I see when trying to use an expired trigger_id:
{
  "ok": false,
  "error": "exchanged_trigger_id"
}

My questions are:

Is there a way to extend the validity of a trigger_id or reissue it later?
How can I handle scenarios where I need to open a modal after a short delay? (e.g., waiting for another user action or confirmation).
What is the recommended approach in Slack for handling delayed modal openings without running into trigger_id expiration issues?

Here is a simplified code that I am using to trigger the modal:
simple_view = {
    "type": "modal",
    "callback_id": "simple_modal",
    "title": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Simple Modal"
    },
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "This is a simple test modal."
            }
        }
    ],
    "submit": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Submit"
    }
}

# Triggering the modal
try:
    slack_client.views_open(trigger_id=trigger_id, view=simple_view)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error opening modal: {e}")


There is no way to extend validity of a trigger_id, but you could use standard approach with loading message or something like this.
So you opening modal immediately and display loading message or may be placeholder. After delay you could update modal with some content using views.update API of slack.
Here is little example:
initial_view = {
    "type": "modal",
    "callback_id": "initial_modal",
    "title": {"type":"plain_text", "text":"Loading..."},
    "blocks":[
         {"type": "section", "text":{"type": "plain_text", "text": "Sorry, loading..."}}
    ]
}
response = slack_client.views_open(trigger_id=trigger_id, view=initial_view)

time.sleep(123)

updated_view = {
    "type": "modal",
    "callback_id":"simple_modal",
    "title": {"type":"plain_text", "text": "Simple Modal"},
    "blocks": [
      {"type":"section", "text": {"type": "mrkdwn", "text": "Some content"}}
    ],
    "submit": {"type": "plain_text","text": "Submit"}
}
slack_client.views_update(view_id=response['view']['id'], view=updated_view)

